# Nginx reverse proxy to Unicorn - nginx configuration is incorrect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy, unicorn

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to configure my rails app to run Unicorn, and be reversed proxy by Nginx on my AWS ubuntu instance.

I am able to access the nginx, "Welcome to nginx!" default page, running on the site from the outside(security is configured properly). But it is not serving the rails app.

My unicorn is running under `/home/ubuntu/appname/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock=`

I ran `sudo service unicorn restart` just in case.
when i run `sudo service --status-all` it returns:
`[ ? ]  unicorn_gpei-tk`

As I mentioned nginx is definitely running, here is the config located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/home/ubuntu/appname/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /home/ubuntu/appname/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

symlink in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` is `default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` -- I guess second question would be: is the sites-enabled necessary? The tutorial does not mention/require it, I came across this after the 1000 other resources I am attempting to decipher this issue.

Other info: if I run Unicorn as a user I am able to connect to it on port 8080, so Unicorn does run on it's own as well and serve the site.

And I've also restarted nginx service a few times as well, still does not update the config, probably because I have it wrong somewhere.

Really am not seeing what I am missing, any clues/ideas? thanks.

**Edit:**

I went into /var/log/nginx/error.log (there's an error.log.1 but it doesnt seem to be updating) and this is showing up:
`2016/07/28 16:21:19 [error] 11763#11763: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: XX.XXX.XXX.XX, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "my_public_address.com", referrer: "http://my_public_address.com/"`

and /var/log/nginx/access.log is:
`XX.XXX.XXX.XX - - [28/Jul/2016:16:24:58 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://my_public_address.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and fixed it.

You need to include the configuration for what you want. in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf comment out the default config because it is pointing to localhost.
add the configuration you want to the here. in my case it was this:
`/etc/nginx/sites-available/*` i only have one config file in there but just felt like putting *.

restart nginx service.
many newbie hours of headache all gone now.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission of /home/ubuntu/appname/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock, see if it can be accessed by nginx running user.

Comment: Couldnt edit my previous comment, deleted it. I all of nginx is under `root` and unicorn/rest of the app is `ubuntu`. Root would have access to ubuntu user?